# python mysql select in class

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, class, typeerror

Unfortunately I've no Idea what's the issue coding in this way. I try to run a select statement within a class - the result is: `TypeError: open_select() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'.`
Does anybody have an idea? Thx in advance

```
class finDB_exec:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbcn = db.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root', 
                                 password='xxx', 
                                 database='xxxx')

        self.dbcr = self.dbcn.cursor()


    def db_commit(self):

        self.dbcn.commit()

    def db_close(self):

        self.dbcr.close()
        self.dbcn.close()

##############################################################################
####    1) Open Select
##############################################################################

    def open_select(self,query):

        try:
            self.cr = self.dbcr()
            self.cr.execute(query)
            self.db_commit()
            result = self.cursor.fetchall()
            return result

        except:
            pass

query = 'Select * from tbl_companies limit 10'
res = finDB_exec.open_select(query)
```

Comment: As an aside, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: `open_select` is an instance method, so you need to call it on an instance of the class, not the class itself: `finDB_exec().open_select(query)`

Comment: `query = 'Select * from tbl_companies'
db_inst = finDB_exec()
res = db_inst.open_select(query)

for row in res:
    print(row)`

Now I got this: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`